# Have agreed or agree?

Tags: present-perfect, present-simple, cleft-constructions

Can anyone help me to find out why (A) structure is wrong and (B) is correct?

> A. when disasters occur in local communities, it is the students who **agree** to help again and again.

> B. when disasters occur in local communities, it is the students who **have agreed** to help again and again.

This is a test from *English Grammar Digest* by Trudy Aronson. Is it because of the meaning?

Comment: Who says (A) is wrong?

Comment: It's simply not true that Simple Present (A) is "wrong" and Present Perfect (B) is "correct". They're different syntactic constructions, which *unavoidably* must convey exactly the same meaning because of ***again [and again]***. Without that qualifier, it would be *possible* to draw the distinction between A: *Present used "timelessly", to signify that this is what always has and always will happen* and B: *Perfect form referring to a single Past action with particular relevance to time of speaking*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on the false premise that one of the cited alternatives is "incorrect"

Comment: Do you mean both of them are correct? It’s a test from English Grammar Digest ( Trudy Aronson )

Comment: Yes, we are all saying A is perfectly correct.

Comment: I choose (A) but what the author has selected is Present Perfect.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Please keep in mind the answer box is only for answers. Please don't post comments or any additional information to the question in the answer box. You should include in your questions **as much information as you possibly can**, and please always tell us the source of your quoted text. If you know the source, don't wait for someone to ask you, just put it in the question. Please look around at other well-received questions and see what good Stack Exchange questions should look like.

Answer (score 1):

[Agree is a verb](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/agree).

"I have agreed" - is a *past participle tense* of it, and it means, that "I have done the act of the agreement sometime ago, in the past, and it is active/valid up until now"; however I don't specify when that agreement took place.

"I agree" - is a "simple present tense" of it, and it means, that I agree, either in general, or in the specific moment.

Therefore, both `A` and `B` are correct, they just have slightly different meanings.